# Is there a way to browser Source Code when pressing F12 if I only have the DLL and PDB files?

Tags: c#, dll, pdb-files

I have a very large solution (384 projects), and I usually work in only one of these projects at a time. So when opening that project alone, pressing F12 brings me only to the metadata page of the used DLL. My project has reference to the DLL files created in the bigger solution.

Is there a way to browse the Source Code when pressing F12 if I only have the DLL and PDB files?

Comment: it's a feature of VS 15 that will be released one day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official way of doing so, but since a lot of years, there's a tool/extension called [***Reflector*** which disassembles MSIL into readable C# code](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

It works exactly as you want... You press <kbd>F12</kbd> and it decompiles the code to show C# code. BTW, it won't never be the exact source code as you developed in your solution. It's a translation back from MSIL to C#.

It's not free, but AFAIK, there's a trial and maybe it's worth the price for you...

Comment: @deadpixelsociety but ILSpy has no integration with Visual Studio if I'm not mistaken. At least with Reflector you can press F12 and see the disassembled C# code

Comment: That's very true, but when pricing comes into the question a little inconvenience can sometimes be accommodated. :)

Comment: It's disappointing to see that you have to decompile the dlls to be able to navigate the source. To clarify, I DO have the source to the dlls, I just don't want the projects in this minor solution, I have them in the bigger solution.

Comment: @BroskMenmi Yeah, I'm agree. At the end of the day, the debugger can open source files when you step into a member from other project which has the source code in your machine.

Comment: @BroskMenmi It seems like VS could also support this without debugging, while *coding*,

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer How do you mean while coding? that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @BroskMenmi I mean that if what you're looking for can be done while debugging, it seems like Microsoft could easily implement the same feature when you press *F12*

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Sorry I got too excited there and thought there was a solution. Yes exactly, there is even an extension called Ref12 that does this for the .NET framework.

Comment: @BroskMenmi Uhm, in my case I need no extension... When you're debugging code and you step into a method from a library which isn't a project reference, the debugger steps into the whole library's source code, if the source code is located in your machine in the same location when the code was built

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer To clarify, the extension works for the .NET source code and enables F12 to the source while not debugging!

Comment: @BroskMenmi Ah, it's interesting, I didn't know it. BTW, this is just querying the Web site to get the source code. I guess it intercepts the command bound to F12 and cancels the default behavior :\

Comment: @BroskMenmi I would try to develop what you want myself, but my experience with VS extensibility is it's tedious to extend VS.......

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains (makers of ReSharper) offer their own MSIL decompiler called dotPeek https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/
You can enable source server support and it will show you the decompiled source code when you F12.